# Selenium: Validating label testing

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

First-all, I apologize if this question is already answered. 
I am trying to automate simple login page for aribaweb application. The following source of my web page for login label.

```
<td class=ffl>
<label for=_$eseed>Login Name:</label></td>
```

Java source code:
I am trying to find out with below piece of code. But, I am not able to go through.

```
iedriver.findElement(By.id("Login Name")).sendKeys("username");
```

I have tried using IDE as well, to check label value. I am seeing same issue
[error] Element id=_$eseed not found

Any help in this regard is much appreciated.

Comment: Please put the entire source of the specific element that you are trying to access (or even provide the URL of the web-page itself), and will be able to give you an answer. The problem is probably that `"Login Name"` is not the ID of the input element to which you are trying to send `"username"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Login Name:` is not an `id` attribute. It is `text`. Instead you need to use the `for` attribute to locate the element. The other important thing is that you CANNOT send keys to `label` tags. There must be an input tag (or equivalent) next to the label where you want to send the text to.

```
WebElement label = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("label[for='_$eseed']"));
s.o.p(label.getText());
```

If you provide html around the label consisting of input, I could point you on how to send keys.

**Edit**
Based on your html, this is what you need,

```
WebElement login = driver.findElement(By.id("_$eseed"));
login.sendKeys("my_username");
```

Comment: <label for=_$eseed>Login Name:</label></td>
<td class=ffi><span id=_fbgoob><img alt="" border=0 height=11 width=10 src=""></span></td>
<td class=ffp>
<input bh=TF class="tf tfW" value="" id=_$eseed type=text name=_2nakec><div class=rr id=_1cpb1c>
</div> <tr id=_wmqizc valign=middle>
<td class=ffl> <label for=_jbshdb>Password:</label></td>
<td class=ffi><span id=_hhegnd><img alt="" border=0 height=11 width=10 src="/h.gif"></span></td>
<td class=ffp>
<input autocomplete=false onCopy="return false" xkeypress="return ariba.Handlers.noCapsLockTxt(event,this, '_l3onid');"

Comment: Thank you for response! Works like Gem!!

Comment: 1 mre Q: I am not able to see Id for button, in this case, how to find the same Appreciate your help! tr id=_vez9u valign=middle>
<td class=ffl>
</td>
<td class=ffi><span id=_hketcc><img alt="" border=0 height=11 width=10 src="gif.f"></span></td>
<td class=ffp>
<table border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 class=btnWrap><tr><td tabIndex=0 bh=TB id=__vogkb class=btn _cl=btn _isdef=true><div class=rbSA><b class="rbC"><b class="rbBC rb1"></b><b class="rbBC rbFC rb2"></b></b><div class="rbBC rbBFC rbB">
Login
</div><b class="rbC"><b class="rbBC rbFC rbBtFC rb2"></b><b class="rbBC rb1"></b></td></tr>

Comment: @user2943946 Please ask a separate question. Posting html in comment is not helpful and recommended. Format html like a code block and post a new question. I would be happy to help.

Comment: Apologies for the same. I have tried multiple things. I got thru, Tq! for your help!!

Answer (score 3):

Can you give whole source code?

I think this is where the problem is:

```
iedriver.findElement(By.id("Login Name")).sendKeys("username");
```

is wrong. You should give your HTML element id to `By.id`. Not your label string.

You can use [FireBug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/) to find HTML elements ids,css and more.

Comment: Sure @Ant's. Here is the source code: `code` public static void main(String[] args) 
   {
 
       WebDriver iedriver = new  FirefoxDriver();
       iedriver.get("http://192.168.250.112:8085/EasyCare/AribaWeb/");

        try {
           Thread.sleep(4000);
            } catch (Exception e) {
         // TODO: handle exception
          }
            iedriver.findElement(By.id("Login Name")).sendKeys("username");   
            iedriver.findElement(By.id("Password:")).sendKeys("passwd");   
            iedriver.findElement(By.id("Login")).click();   

}

Comment: `By.id("Login Name")` is wrong. Your passing label to `id`, instead of id of that html element.

Comment: OK! Is this right way to do that? iedriver.findElement(By.id("_$seed")).sendKeys("username"); But, still says it Unable to locate element

Comment: No. Its not. Ok fine, there is no id to your html element. Try xpath instead.